# JavaScript: Slider jumps to the wrong ID every 2 steps

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've built a custom, dirt and quick, jQuery/JavaScript slider... which works great, except for one issue.

When using the 'Previous' button, it works perfectly the first time you click it, but then when you click it again, the length of the array becomes '2' when it should be '1' because there are only two results...

Code:

```
      jQuery("#sliderNext").click(function(event) {
    $("#sliderNext").fadeOut(50);
    $("#sliderPrevious").fadeOut(50);
    setTimeout(function() {
                $("#sliderNext").fadeIn(100);
                $("#sliderPrevious").fadeIn(100);
            }, 900);
      slideNumber++;
      if(slideNumber < image.length && caption.length) {
        jQuery(".slider-image").css("background-image", "url(" + image[slideNumber] + ")");
        jQuery("#caption").text(caption[slideNumber]);
        console.log("if: " + slideNumber);
      }
      else
      {
        slideNumber = 0;
        jQuery(".slider-image").css("background-image", "url(" + image[slideNumber] + ")");
        jQuery("#caption").text(caption[slideNumber]);
        console.log("else: " + slideNumber);
      }

  });

   jQuery("#sliderPrevious").click(function(event) {
    $("#sliderNext").fadeOut(50);
    $("#sliderPrevious").fadeOut(50);
    setTimeout(function() {
                $("#sliderNext").fadeIn(100);
                $("#sliderPrevious").fadeIn(100);
            }, 900);
      slideNumber--;
     console.log(image.length);
      if(slideNumber >= 0 && slideNumber <= image.length) {
        jQuery(".slider-image").css("background-image", "url(" + image[slideNumber] + ")");
        jQuery("#caption").text(caption[slideNumber]);
        console.log("if: " + slideNumber);
      }
      else
      {
        slideNumber = image.length;
        jQuery(".slider-image").css("background-image", "url(" + image[slideNumber] + ")");
        jQuery("#caption").text(caption[slideNumber]);
        console.log("else: " + slideNumber);
        console.log(image.length);
      }

  });
```

I've tried using different operators, if/else statements, it always sets it to 2 on the second click.

Could anybody point me in the right direction for why it would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because your click event gets bound the second time to the button and therefore jumps twice.

Try to "unbind" your click events before binding them.

```
$("#sliderPrevious").unbind();
// and then
jQuery("#sliderPrevious").click(function(event) {...});
```

Do this to every event that gets bound when intializing the page.

**EDIT**

```
var myArray = [a,b];
```

Note that `myArray.length == 2` but `myArray[2]` is undefined.

Array indexes start at [0] thats why you have to substract 1 from your "counter" variable.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that didn't resolve it... it still does the same, bounces from 0 on the 'if' statement, straight to '2' on the else statement.

Comment: I sadly don't have the time to dive deep into this, but incrementing a value should be done in the end of a function. Also how can slideNumber be 2 in the else when you set it to 0 there?

Comment: On the sliderPrevious, it is set equal to the length of the 'image' array... which has two results, so it should be either 0 or 1, not 0, 1 or 2 (because arrays start from 0). So I've no clue why image.length is throwing 2.

Comment: Javascript.length throws you back the exact number of indexes. So if the array has [0] and [1] it finds two indexes and therefore the length equals to two. so you have to substract 1 to get the correct index like that. I have edited my answer

Comment: That got it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help :)